# How to show the menu of PopupMenuButton from the code

Tags: flutter

PopupMenuButton opens a menu when user clicks on it. But how do I do open the same menu at the same place as the PopupMenuButton from the code(e.g. due to another user event)?

I am trying to create a nested menu in the AppBar. Like when user clicks on "Sort by" then menu changes to something else. Is there another way to achieve this? I could not find it on the internet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take a look at [the sources of `PopupMenuButton`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/7a4c33425d/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/popup_menu.dart#L898) you can see that it uses `showMenu` method which is accessible even out of the button's context (potentially comes along with imported `material` Dart class).

Define a `GlobalKey` variable and apply it to your `PopupMenuButton` to have a reference to the context of your button - that's how we get the position of the button on the screen.

Create an array of items for the menu, later to reuse it in both the programmatic call and the physical button itself.

Calculate the position for the menu to appear at, and make the `showMenu` call.

`showMenu` returns a Future - listen to its completion to get the chosen item.

---

```dart
// Define these variables somewhere accessible by both the button on `build` & by the programmatic call.

final popupButtonKey = GlobalKey<State>(); // We use `State` because Flutter libs do not export `PopupMenuButton` state specifically.

final List<PopupMenuEntry> menuEntries = [
  PopupMenuItem(
    value: 1,
    child: Text('One'),
  ),
  PopupMenuItem(
    value: 2,
    child: Text('Two'),
  ),
];
```

In your `build`:

```dart
PopupMenuButton(
  key: popupButtonKey,
  initialValue: null,
  itemBuilder: (_) => menuEntries,
  // ...
);
```

To show the menu programmatically:

```dart
// Here we get the render object of our physical button, later to get its size & position
final RenderBox popupButtonObject = popupButtonKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();

// Get the render object of the overlay used in `Navigator` / `MaterialApp`, i.e. screen size reference
final RenderBox overlay = Overlay.of(context).context.findRenderObject();

// Calculate the show-up area for the dropdown using button's size & position based on the `overlay` used as the coordinate space.
final RelativeRect position = RelativeRect.fromRect(
  Rect.fromPoints(
    popupButtonObject.localToGlobal(Offset.zero, ancestor: overlay),
    popupButtonObject.localToGlobal(popupButtonObject.size.bottomRight(Offset.zero), ancestor: overlay),
  ),
  Offset.zero & overlay.size, // same as: new Rect.fromLTWH(0.0, 0.0, overlay.size.width, overlay.size.height)
);

// Finally, show the menu.
showMenu(
  context: context,
  elevation: 8.0, // default value
  items: menuEntries,
  initialValue: null,
  position: position,
).then((res) {
  print(res);
});
```

Comment: works like a charm. thanks. i didnt know about GlobalKey before. The comments in the code helped a lot.

Comment: [GlobalKey](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlobalKey-class.html) is a relatively expensive way to get a reference for a widget. But it is perfectly suitable for your case as `PopupMenuButton` is unique, I suppose.

Another thing to keep in mind is that `popupButtonKey.currentContext` can be null if the button is not initialised yet.

Comment: @George how would one do a less expensive way?

Comment: @omega_prime as long as you don't overuse it (no more than one key per a widget) - you should be just fine.

Comment: @George Thanks, though I am unsure of how to actually do this using your code. I am trying to emulate this to use as an autocomplete as plugins for the web don't seem to work. Are you please able to edit your code to give a more complete example for me and anyone else who may be stuck. Thanks a lot

Comment: @omega_prime if you're trying to make this work on Flutter Web - I don't think I can help you. I've never had a chance to try it out. You might want to use Dialogs (e.g. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AlertDialog-class.html) with clickable `ListTile` to achieve a similar effect that `PopupMenuButton` provides.

Comment: @George I am VERY close to it, literaly just the programatically opening part now. Wouldn't AlertDialog take over the screen, thereby making it quite difficult? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62024669/is-there-a-working-autocomplete-text-field-form-for-flutter-web is my current progress